# how to add the font awesome icon in after before elements

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Hi i am trying to add the font awesome icon in before and after elements.But i do not know how to write its css and how to get font awesome icons links to put it in the after before css.

I have created a structure like this.

```html
 <html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
 </head>
 <style>
  .thish{position:relative; height:150px; width:150px ; background:red;  }
  .thish::before{position:absolute; content:'tyjthsrgd';right:40%; color:#000; bottom:0; height:30px; width:60px; background:green; z-index:1; }
 </style>
 
 <body>
  <div class="thish"> 
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Font Awesome 5 has [examples about this](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js#pseudo-elements) (though you're using v4.7.0).

Comment: If my answer helped u then please accept it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add to to your `before` **pseudo** selector

```
   content: "\f2ba";
   font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
```

To get the value of `content`, go to their [website](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/),

Right-click -> Inspect any icon (`<i> ::before </i>` tag) and then check the value of the content in the `before` **pseudo** selector.

Dont forget to put the value of font

`normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;`

This is very important.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

</head>
<style>
  .thish {
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background: red;
  }
  
  .thish::before {
    position: absolute;
   content: "\f2ba";
   font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    right: 40%;
    color: #000;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    background: green;
    z-index: 1;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div class="thish">
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to include the icon and also have text with it? Something like `content: "\f2ba - message that appears next to icon"`

Answer (score 3):

**For Fontawesome 4**

You just have to add the following CSS to your after or before element:

```
font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
content: '\f042';
```

Here the `content` is the icon you want to add. Just copy the Unicode of the icon from the FA website and paste it in the content with a `\` prefix.

```css
.thish {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
}

.thish::before {
  position: absolute;
  font:normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  content: '\f042';
  right: 40%;
  color: #000;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  background: green;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="thish">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.