# How to add Chevron at the end of each list item, aligned from the right

Tags: html, css

I want to add a Chevron, at the end of each `li`, and I want to align all the Chevrons 5px from the end of the `ul`, like the image below:

[image]

How can I achive this?

```css
ul {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Cars</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Real Estate</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Fashion</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
</ul>
```

P.S. I am using font [awesome's chevron](https://fontawesome.com/icons/chevron-right): `<i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:after` selector for this

```css
ul {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 120px;
}
ul li a:after {
  content:">";
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Cars</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Real Estate</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Fashion</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
</ul>
```

Or using Fontawesome

```css
ul {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 120px;
}
ul li a .fas {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Cars <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Real Estate <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Fashion <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sports <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can get the best of both worlds by using font-awesome in the first example as well. Just set the `:after` to use font awesomes font and change the `content` to have the correct char (use the one the fontawesome css are using for that icon.) [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50559557/2453432)

Comment: Much better than using fa

Answer (score 2):

I used:

```
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
```

Also, these shivrons work as links.

```css
ul {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 120px;
}

ul li i{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Cars <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Real Estate <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Fashion <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sports <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```